# Gtk2Hs set local format in a program or a widget

Tags: haskell, localization, gtk, gtk2hs

I'm trying to set the locale format of a spin button. The decimal mark on my system is a comma `,` and I would like it to become a dot `.`.

Is there a function in GTK or Glib to set the locale formatting globally or locally on a widget.

I looked in hackage functions named `local`, `format`, `decimal`, ... in GTK and Glib but I didn't find the appropriate function.

I have read it is possible to set the output manually with the function `entrySetText` but I'm looking for a global setting.

Do you know how to change locale format globally in a Gtk program? The correct function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to have the correct format in the spinbutton entry by setting the text with the `entrySetText` function :

```
onValueSpinned spin $  do
    val <- spinButtonGetValue spin
    entrySetText spin $ printf "%6.2f" val
    return ()
```

The entry text is modified each time the value of the spinbutton is changed. The decimal mark used by `printf` is a dot `.` and is correct now.

The following code snippet work too :

```
onOutput spin $  do
    val <- spinButtonGetValue spin
    entrySetText spin $ printf "%6.2f" val
    return True
```